# Executing raw query ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to execute de following query:

```
query = "select v.price, v.quantity, p.title, v.product_id from variants v join products p on (v.product_id = p.id) where (v.price,v.product_id) in (select min(price),product_id from variants group by product_id);"
```

When I do `results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)` in the rails console I get:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: select v.price, v.quantity, p.title, v.product_id from variants v join products p on (v.product_id = p.id) where (v.price,v.product_id) in (select min(price),product_id from variants group by product_id)
```

I am sure that all the commas are in place and the statement is pretty well written at least for Oracle . Where is my mistake ?

Comment: you have to write the query in a single line.. not the way you wrote......

Comment: ok that got rid of 1 problem , i am left with another

Comment: tell what is second ?.......

Comment: i updated the question. It is the one that you see there

Comment: Are you also using an Oracle-DB for your query (just to be sure there are no dialect variants). An can you try the command without the trailing `;`?

Comment: Yeah i was checking every inch. And everything is good until (v.price,v.product_id) I don't think it likes this construction... Until that is good, and after "IN" it;s also good. As a db i am using SQLite3

Comment: Yes I already tried it without ;

Comment: I am 99% sure that it doesn't like the construction (v.price,v.product_id). Could i replace it with something ? select v.price, v.quantity, p.title, v.product_id from variants v join products p on (v.product_id = p.id) where (v.price,v.product_id) in (1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,89,9,0)
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: select v.price, v.quantity, p.title, v.product_id from variants v join products p on (v.product_id = p.id) where (v.price,v.product_id) in (1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,89,9,0)

Comment: I just tried your SQL with sqlite 3 and get also a syntax error. So it is a dialect problem.

Comment: If you give it parts of it everything is fine. You just can give SQLite3 this part  (v.price,v.product_id) . But I need it . I need to get the lowest price(it's in Variants) of every product along with the name(it's in Products) and quantity(it's in Variants)

Comment: Are you sure the in-operator can handle multiple values?

Comment: I am pretty sure that if it wouldn't be able to do that then it's existence would have no purpose. Plus if you write Product.includes(:variants) it will use the IN operator and put all the ids of the Products to get the variants . So in the end my answer is 100% yes.

Comment: Can you provide an example with create statement and some test data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78605/discussion-between-lucian-tarna-and-knut).

Comment: yes this statement works just fine "select v.price, v.quantity, p.title, v.product_id from variants v join products p on (v.product_id = p.id)" . I ran it and it gave me the expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems sqlite3 doesn't supper th in-operator with multiple values (`where (v.price,v.product_id) in (select min(price),product_id...`)

From discussion the question behind is:

> I need to get the lowest price(it's in Variants) of every product along 
>   with the name(it's in Products) and quantity(it's in Variants)

Based on this I recommend this SQL-statement:

```
SELECT min(`v`.`price`) AS 'min_price', `v`.`quantity`, `p`.`title`, `v`.`product_id` FROM `variants` AS 'v' INNER JOIN `products` AS 'p' ON (`v`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`) GROUP BY `product_id`
```

or same statement in a human readable version:

```
SELECT 
  min(`v`.`price`) AS 'min_price', 
  `v`.`quantity`, `p`.`title`, `v`.`product_id`
FROM `variants` AS 'v' 
INNER JOIN `products` AS 'p' 
  ON (`v`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`) 
GROUP BY `product_id`
```

I don't use rails and active record, I used sequel to get this solution. Here is my complete script to test the code:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite('test.db')
Sequel.extension :core_extensions
Sequel.extension :pretty_table

#if called 2nd time with a db-file
DB.drop_table(:variants) if DB.table_exists?(:variants)
DB.drop_table(:products) if DB.table_exists?(:products)

DB.create_table :products do |t| 
  primary_key :id
  t.string :title 
  t.string :description 
  t.timestamps null: false 
end 
DB.create_table :variants do |t| 
  primary_key :id
  t.boolean :is_active 
  t.integer :price 
  t.integer :quantity 
  t.timestamps null: false 

  foreign_key :product_id, :products
end 

class Product < Sequel::Model; end
class Variant < Sequel::Model; end

10.times do |g| 
  Product.create(title: "Prod %02i" % g, description: "Who Cares..") 
end 

 100.times do |c| 
   Variant.create(
    price: (rand(100)).ceil, quantity: (rand(10).ceil).floor , 
    product_id: Product[rand(1..10).floor].id
   ) 
 end

puts DB.tables

sel = DB[:variants.as(:v)]
  .select(Sequel.function(:min,:v__price).as(:min_price), :v__quantity, :p__title, :v__product_id)
  .join(:products.as(:p), :v__product_id => :p__id)
  .group_by(:product_id)

puts sel.sql

Sequel::PrettyTable.print(sel)
```

The result is:

```
SELECT min(`v`.`price`) AS 'min_price', `v`.`quantity`, `p`.`title`, `v`.`product_id` FROM `variants` AS 'v' INNER JOIN `products` AS 'p' ON (`v`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`) GROUP BY `product_id`
+---------+----------+--------+-------+
|min_price|product_id|quantity|title  |
+---------+----------+--------+-------+
|        1|         1|       5|Prod 00|
|       12|         2|       9|Prod 01|
|       21|         3|       6|Prod 02|
|        1|         4|       0|Prod 03|
|       34|         5|       8|Prod 04|
|       11|         6|       8|Prod 05|
|       14|         7|       9|Prod 06|
|        7|         8|       8|Prod 07|
|       11|         9|       8|Prod 08|
|       21|        10|       8|Prod 09|
+---------+----------+--------+-------+
```

(Values may differ for your execution, there are random values in the data creation).